# EF4 CTP5 CodeFirst modeling problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

i am new at EF4 CTP5 and i want to create a model below like,each table are same fields(id,text,value),i dont want to put all of them in one table,can i use a base class?but i dont know that how is it be my domain model?

```
public class BaseSearchType
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int text{get;set;}
   public int value {get;set;}
}

public class BooleanSearchTypeTable :BaseSearchType
{

}

public class JobStatusSearchTypeTable:BaseSearchType
{

}

public class PersonStatusSearchTypeTable: BaseSearchType
{

}
```

Tables

```
BooleanSearchTypeTable 
-----------------
id text value
1   All  0
2   Yes  1
3   No   2

JobStatusSearchTypeTable
-----------------
id text value
1   Open  0
2   Closed  1
3   Approved   2
4   Rejected 3
5   Waiting 4

PersonStatusSearchTypeTable
id text value
1   Work 0
2   Seek 1
3   Vacation 2
```

Comment: You should upgrade to the release version.  It's been out for over a month.  EF 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will not be mapped into one table until you instruct EF to do that. Simply define your classes like:

```
public abstract class BaseSearchType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class BooleanSearchTypeTable : BaseSearchType
{ }

public class JobStatusSearchTypeTable : BaseSearchType
{ }

public class PersonStatusSearchTypeTable : BaseSearchType
{ }
```

And your context like:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<JobStatusSearchTypeTable> JobStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BooleanSearchTypeTable> BooleanStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PersonStatusSearchTypeTable> PersonStatuses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you not just dbset the base class e.g., public DbSet<BaseSearchType> BaseSearchType{ get; set; }

Comment: Once you do it you have the entity inheritance and all entities mapped to the single table which is what OP doesn't want. You can modify it to other type of inheritances but still that is something you should do only if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "POCO" model, it may help in this scenario

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/28/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-2-complex-types-deferred-loading-and-explicit-loading.aspx